How to pass on raw html in FastHTML
I'm trying to handle raw html and pass it onto fasthtml

from fasthtml.common import *
...

@rt('/test/')
def test():
    raw_content1 = "<button>button 1</button>"
    return Div( ft_html(raw_content1) )


getting this instead of a div wrapped button
 <div>
<<button>button 1</button>></<button>button 1</button>>     </div>



How do I properly handle that in FastHTML?

you can use NotStr:
from fasthtml.common import *
...

@rt('/test/')
def test():
    raw_content1 = "<button>button 1</button>"
    return Div( NotStr(raw_content1) )

